# ASP.NET Configuration on hosted (Godaddy.com)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I been developing a website with MVC3/EFCode First/C#, everything ok, I tested multiple times on my computer and all perfect.

I used ASP.NET membership to manage permissions, and the administration web that provides Visual Studio 2010 (the little button on the Solution Explorer with a Hammer and a Little World), that launch a website where i can add more users, roles, and some configurations. I used the feature that enables you to add users, to add an "admin user" to the platform that create all the other users... but i NEED this first user on my membership table (so i can log-in and create all the stuff that the website use).

The trouble that I have is that I hosted the website on Godaddy using the publish tool on Visual Studio, everything ok, I create the database and the connection strings are ok, but I don't have this "Control Panel" to add the first user...

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the structure of the database to your remote server. Now you need to add the *contents* of your Asp.Net membership tables to the GoDaddy copy as well.

For example, see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx, and you can find

> Database deployment settings for deploying to staging servers and production servers are like the settings that you entered for the Debug build configuration. The difference is that you do not want to deploy the test user accounts that you entered into the ASP.NET membership system. However, you cannot just specify Schema Only database deployment for the ASP.NET membership database. This is because one of the tables in the database contains configuration data that is required for the ASP.NET membership system. Therefore, you will create a custom script to add the configuration data.

At [this location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd579608.aspx)